Typescript Json get value
I'm getting from api   {"bmw":[{"year":2022, "color": "black", "perfs":{"bmw":{"model": "x5", "county": "Germany"}}, "price":35000}]}
How can I get the values of the model and country by the typescript, map() function?
I am trying to get the value of the country and model of the car, to show in a table in the frontend.

• Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can use to see what you're seeing. The code you're showing isn't valid JSON. Where are you getting it from? Is it some console log? Or a string you get from the API? • What does "to front table" mean? I'm not quite understanding the question; maybe it's a language barrier?

What exact output are you expecting? You could write console.log(resp.bmw.map(x => x.perfs.bmw.county + " " + x.perfs.bmw.model)) but I have no idea if that's what you're looking for.

Indeed. You dont show the model or interface that you are using.
